# Gstreamer: Encode microphone audio using AAC encode to mp4

Tags: audio, gstreamer

Wondering if it is possible to encode using AAC into mp4 container

I have tried using the following

```
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc device="hw:0,0" ! "audio/x-raw,rate=48000,channels=2,depth=16" ! queue ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac !  qtmux ! filesink location=audio.mp4
```

The program runs without a fault but when I inspect the file content, it gives me a null content

However when i run with avimux, the file content gives the encoding and details like lenght of audio

```
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc device="hw:0,0" ! "audio/x-raw,rate=48000,channels=2,depth=16" ! queue ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac !  avimux ! filesink location=audio.mp4
```

Wander what is wrong as I would need AAC encoding (for later rtsp streaming) and need to use mp4 as container and qtmux

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't really say what you are doing exactly. But most likely you are missing the `-e` option for `gst-launch-1.0`. With that an EOS signal is propagated through the pipleine to correctly finalize the mp4 file. Other file formats are not that picky, but mp4 needs to write a proper index when all samples have been written.

Comment: Hi actually I am trying to test out part of my pipeline with gstreamer-launch before i commit to coding in C.. Test for helping

Comment: I think the important detail missing in your description here is that you abort the encoding with CTRL-C which is causing the MP4 corruption. But does it work for you with the `-e` switch?

Comment: Hi how do you actually end the program? I mean can we use Ctrl Z?

Comment: I channced upon you comments in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329968/video-is-much-faster-than-audio-when-muxed-in-gstreamer. Now i know what to do